In what ways does the properties of infinity alter or invalidate this epsilon-delta proof?
Disclaimer: I am following a math textbook which has not really covered the properties of infinities yet. Only introduced the concept in the context of limits.
I have the following problem in my textbook:

Use the delta-epsilon definition of limits to prove that:
$$\lim_{x\to 0⁺} \frac{1}{x} = \infty$$

My method for proving the statement above would be to prove the following:
$(\forall \epsilon \in \mathbb{R}_{>0})(\exists \delta \in \mathbb{R}_{>0})(|x - 0| < \delta \implies |\frac{1}{x} - \infty| < \epsilon)$
Until now I have only done epsilon-delta proofs for converging functions and have therefore not dealt with expressions containing infinities like: $|\frac{1}{x} - \infty| < \epsilon)$
If $\infty$ was a real number $a$ which one could use normal arithmetic on. I would do the following:
$\epsilon \in \mathbb{R}_{>0} \implies 0 < \frac{1}{x} - a < \epsilon \implies \frac{1}{x} - a < \epsilon$
$x \in \mathbb{R}_{>0} \implies \frac{1}{x} - a < \epsilon \iff x > \frac{1}{\epsilon + a}$
$\delta < \frac{1}{\epsilon + a}$
So to get $\frac{1}{x}$ closer to infinity than a given distance $\epsilon$. You would have to let the distance between $x$ and $0$ be less than $\frac{1}{\epsilon + \infty} \approx 0$ which makes logical sense (I think). But:
(1) I don't know if I am allowed  to perform all the operations on $\infty$ like I just did on $a$ in the solution above.
(2) Isn't $|\frac{1}{x} - \infty|$ undefined when $\frac{1}{x} \to \infty$ as $\infty - \infty$ is undefined?

Man, this is not a good question for the textbook to be asking. Infinity is not part of the reals, so epsilon delta proofs make no sense, as that requires at least a notion of a metric. As a bandaid, I suggest that for infinity, just prove that for all n above 0, there's a delta for which $|x-0| < \delta$ implies $\frac{1}{x} > n$. It's not an epsilon-delta proof, but the closest you can get with infinity.

Your definition makes no sense since $;\infty;$ isn't a real number. What should be proved is $$\forall,R >0;\exists,\delta >0;;s.t.;; 0<x<\delta\implies \frac1x>R$$

The infinite analog for $\epsilon$-neighborhood around some finite value is arbitrarily large.

How does the text define $\infty$? As you've noticed expressions like $\frac1x - \infty$ are problematic which is why we don't treat $\infty$ as a number.

@CyclotomicField I went through the earlier chapters and checked if there was a definition of $\infty$. But no precise definition is ever given, its just presented and the concept off "never ending".
